# Delay in JQuery Function (Button Load State)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, button

I have form validation set up to where it will create some Google Documents using Ajax requests and then submit the form to create an entry in a database, once everything in the form is validated.

The actions to be taken **after validation** are specified by the `submitHandler`:

```
submitHandler: function(form) {
    $('#submitButton').button('loading');
    success1.show();
    error1.hide();
    var eName = $('#create_event').find('input[name="eventName"]').val();
    var eDate = $('#create_event').find('input[name="eventDate"]').val();
    var eType = $('#create_event').find('input[name="eventType"]').val();

    function getAgenda(eName, eDate, eType) {
        var result = null;
        var separator = "&";
        var scriptUrl = "http://example.net/libraries/upload.php?fType=agnd" + separator + "eName=" + eName + separator + "eDate=" + eDate + separator + "eType=" + eType;
        $.ajax({
            url: scriptUrl,
            type: 'get',
            dataType: 'html',
            async: false,
            success: function(data) {
                result = data;
            }
        });
        return result;
    }

    function getMin(eName, eDate, eType) {
        var result = null;
        var separator = "&";
        var scriptUrl = "http://example.net/libraries/upload.php?fType=min" + separator + "eName=" + eName + separator + "eDate=" + eDate + separator + "eType=" + eType;
        $.ajax({
            url: scriptUrl,
            type: 'get',
            dataType: 'html',
            async: false,
            success: function(data) {
                result = data;
            }
        });
        return result;
    }
    var agenda = $("<input>").attr("type", "hidden").attr("name", "agendaURL").val(getAgenda(eName, eDate, eType));
    $('#create_event').append($(agenda));
    var min = $("<input>").attr("type", "hidden").attr("name", "minURL").val(getMin(eName, eDate, eType));
    $('#create_event').append($(min));
    form[0].submit();
}
```

The submit button does not get placed into the "loading" state until moments before the form submits. If I remove the Ajax requests then the loading state happens on click, whereas with the Ajax requests it is extremely delayed.

I set the button to the loading state in the second line.

An example of what I mean can be found here: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons-stateful

Any help would be appreciated, thank you for your time in advance.

Here is my fix:

```
        submitHandler: function(form) {
          $('#submitButton').button('loading');
          console.log('Loading Button');
          $("#cancelButton").prop("disabled", true);
          console.log('Disable Button');
          success1.show();
          error1.hide();
          var eName = $('#create_event').find('input[name="eventName"]').val();
          var eDate = $('#create_event').find('input[name="eventDate"]').val();
          var eType = $('#create_event').find('select[name="eventType"]').val();
          var separator = "&";
          var agendaURL = "http://example.net/libraries/upload.php?fType=agnd" + separator + "eName=" + eName + separator + "eDate=" + eDate + separator + "eType=" + eType;
          var minURL = "http://example.net/libraries/upload.php?fType=min" + separator + "eName=" + eName + separator + "eDate=" + eDate + separator + "eType=" + eType;
          var agendaReturn = getAgenda(agendaURL);
          console.log('Called getAgenda');
          agendaReturn.success(function(data) {
            $('input[name="agendaURL"]').val(data);
            console.log('Assigned agendaURL hidden');
          });
          var minReturn = getMin(minURL);
          console.log('Called getMin');
          minReturn.success(function(data) {
            $('input[name="minURL"]').val(data);
            console.log('Assigned minURL hidden');
            submitForm();
            console.log('Form submit called');
          });

          function submitForm() {
            console.log('Form submitting');
            $('#create_event').unbind().submit();
          }

          function getAgenda(agendaURL) {
            return $.ajax({
              url: agendaURL,
              type: 'get',
              dataType: 'text',
              async: true,
            });
          }

          function getMin(minURL) {
            return $.ajax({
              url: minURL,
              type: 'get',
              dataType: 'text',
              async: true,
            });
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried

```
  async:true;
```

I think it should work.

Comment: The load state for the button appears on click. However, the Ajax requests don't seem to work. When `async` was `false`, the Ajax requests returned links that submitted to the database. I do not see them with `async:true;`.

Comment: So I set `async:true;` and commented out `form[0].submit();`. The documents seem to be created in Google Drive both when `async` is `true` and `false`. The only difference is with `async:true;`, the values of the hidden inputs don't appear in the database. Perhaps due to how quickly the code runs? I am currently trying to add some sort of delay/wait to see if that makes a difference.